# Python assert is lying? 1 != 1

Tags: python, django, assertions

I've a piece of code

```
   assert (len(max_test_scores) != 1), \
          "Internal error - migration 0011 - module Programs." \
          " Please contact with developers - " + str(len(max_test_scores))
```

And during execution this code, I've got an assertion error:

> AssertionError: Internal error - migration 0011 - module Programs. Please contact with  developers - 1

So 1 != 1 ?

I was searching, googling and thinking how this can happend, but have no idea. Here is code with it's context

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    problems_and_groups = orm.Test.objects \
            .values('problem', 'group').distinct()

    problems_instances_and_groups = []
    for pi in orm['contests.ProblemInstance'].objects.all():
        for pg in problems_and_groups:
            if pi.problem.pk == pg['problem']:
                problems_instances_and_groups \
                        .append({'problem_instance': pi.pk,
                                 'group': pg['group']})

    count = len(problems_instances_and_groups)
    num = 0
    update_every = max(1, count / 20)
    pb = ProgressBar(count)
    print "Migrating %d groups" % count
    for pig in problems_instances_and_groups:
        if num % update_every == 0:
            pb.update(num)
        num += 1

        submissions = orm['contests.Submission'].objects \
                .filter(problem_instance = pig['problem_instance']) \
                .values('pk')

        print submissions

        submission_reports = orm['contests.SubmissionReport'].objects \
                .filter(submission__in = submissions).values('pk')

        print submission_reports

        test_reports = orm.TestReport.objects \
                .filter(test_group = pig['group'],
                        submission_report__in = submission_reports)

        max_score = None

        max_test_scores = frozenset(test_report.test.max_score
                for test_report in test_reports)

        assert (len(max_test_scores) != 1), \
                "Internal error - migration 0011 - module Programs." \
                " Please contact with developers - " + str(len(max_test_scores))

        max_score = ScoreValue(list(max_test_scores)[0])

        GroupReport.filter(test_group=pig['group'],
                submission_report__in = submission_reports) \
                .update(max_score=max_score)
```

Comment: Where are you demonstrating that `len(max_test_scores)` is not equal to `1`?

Comment: @LukasGraf In the assertion message.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Yes, because str(len(max_test_scores)) is equal to 1

Comment: @bdfhjk that's the assertion you make. And it fails. So `len(max_test_scores)` obviously *is* equal to `1`. But you're telling us it isn't, hence "Python is lying". And your example doesn't contain the necessary data to show otherwise.

Comment: Okay guys, I got where was the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An assertion fails when the expression is *not true*:

```
>>> val = 1
>>> assert val != 1, 'Oops, val is 1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: Oops, val is 1
```

The assertion expression must evaluate to true for the assertion not to fail.

If you want to assert that the set length is 1, then test *for equality*.

You don't need quite as many backslashes either:

```
assert len(max_test_scores) == 1, (
    "Internal error - migration 0011 - module Programs. "
    "Please contact with developers - {}".format(len(max_test_scores)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`assert` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) throws an `AssertionError` if the assertion is `False`.

In this case, it obviously is, because in your example, `len(max_test_scores)` returns `1` (as seen in the `assert` error message, and `1 != 1` is `False`.